# Is there a way to find a custom mongo dbpath?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I set a custom dbpath for mongo and can't remember what it was.  Is there a way to find all mongodb data files so I can locate my data?

I know, I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to search for mongod.lock file in your file system. This file is created in a database directory for both WiredTiger and mmapv1 engines.

If you ran mongod from Linux command line check the history.

Comment: `mongod.lock` is apparently nowhere in my system.

Answer (score 0):

`dbpath` can be set via :

- `mongod --dbpath <your_db_path>`
- `mongod --config configuration.file` where configuration contains an entry like that : `dbpath=<yourdb_path>`

By default, mongo comes with a service script (for Linux located in `/etc/init.d/mongod`) which will launch mongod at boot. For me it contains:

```
CONF=/etc/mongodb.conf
mongod --config $CONF
```

The `CONF` variable may have a different value on your system

If you want to find your mongo dbpath, you have to look at this configuration file.

You can set manually `dbpath` with `mongod --dbpath /var/mongo/data` but if you restart mongod service, it will take into account the one from mongod service script

Note also that from man mongod :

> Unless specified, mongod will look for data files in the default >/data/db directory. (Windows systems use the \data\db directory.) If you >installed using a package  management  system.
>                Check the /etc/mongodb.conf file provided by your packages >to see the configuration of the dbpath.